# Using Java, how can I restrict an object property to have certain values?

Tags: java, object, static-members

Using Java, how can I restrict an object property to have certain values?   I want to create a Java object that represents a "type of location" but I want to restrict the use of the class to only about 100 strings representing all possible types?  What is the design pattern for this?

All I can think of is to create a String arraylist and each time a user instantiates the object I would iterate through the entire list looking for a match.   That seems sorta like a hack to me though and I want to do it right.

Comment: Is this list static (i.e. to update it you have to recompile/deploy your code) or dynamic (i.e. it can change at runtime)?  There being 100 options already makes me suspect the available options might need to change regularly, unless it's modelling something very stable like playing card ranks.

Comment: I was thinking of it as static.  Yes, fixed just like playing card ranks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using Java's [Enumerations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)? Your Object would just by the type of that Enum and then you'd be bounded by the 100 or so Strings you have in your enum.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I thought of that but hadn't ever seen an enum "set" this large before and so I was scared of doing it.   Thanks for validating that its ok.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a HashSet of allowed values (lookup is faster and you only want to know if its contained) for strings or an enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

For a fixed set of 100 or so values, an `enum` type is the best answer.  There are a couple of caveats though:

- If the set of value is **not** fixed ... to the extent that you can hard-wire them into your code ... then `enum` classes won't work.  There is no form of `enum` class in Java that allows you to add new values to an existing enum class without a recompilation, etcetera.
- If you have a **really large** number of values, the `enum` class will run into one or more limitations that are imposed by the JVM spec.  For instance, the static initialization code generated by the compiler for the `enum` class cannot consist of more than 64K of bytecodes.

Answer (score 0):

Another thought, since it's a bounded set, would be to create an enum for those Strings.  Make the object property an enum type.  No worries then.